# Dichromate in acidic medium

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, redox, transition-metals

We were taught that $\ce{Cr_2O_7^{2-}}$ (dichromate) in $\ce{H_2SO_4}$ gives $\ce{CrO_3}$

$$\ce{Cr_2O_7^{2-} +H_2SO_4 -> CrO_3 + ...}$$

Link: [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium_trioxide#Production.2C_structure.2C_and_basic_reactions)

But we know that dichromate in acidic medium converts to $\rm Cr(III)$.

$$\ce{ Cr_2O^{2−}_7 + 14 H3O+ + 6 e− → 2 Cr^{3+} + 7 H2O}$$

Link: [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromate_and_dichromate#Oxidation.E2.80.93reduction_properties)

How is this possible?

Comment: Your question answers itself! With $H_2 SO4$, we get $CrO_3$. With $H_3 O^+$, we get $Cr^{3+}$.

Comment: It's a matter of concentration

Comment: The first reaction is in anhydrous $\ce{H2SO4}$. The second reaction is in an aqueous acidic solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both statements on the behaviour of $\ce{Cr2O7^{2-}}$ are true, but you are confusing two different reactions.

The formation of chromium trioxide from (sodium) dichromate in sulfuric acd is **not** a redox reaction. There is no partner that could be oxidized by $\ce{Cr2O7^{2-}}$. Concentrated sulfuric acid is an oxidant itself and metals like copper are dissolved (oxidized to $\ce{Cu^{2+}}$) while not hydrogen is generated.

Remember also that sulfuric acid is a strong, oxidizing and **dehydrating acid**. This effect is used in the production of $\ce{CrO3}$, which can be considered the *anhydride* of chromic acid ($\ce{H2CrO4}$). Note that chromium in $\ce{Cr2O7^{2-}}$, $\ce{H2CrO4}$, and $\ce{CrO3}$ always has the same oxidation state.

The second reaction that you mentioned does happen too, and this is indeed part of a redox reaction in which $\ce{Cr(VI)}$ is reduced to $\ce{Cr(III)}$. However, this can only happen when a suitable reaction partner is present, which in turn is oxidized by $\ce{Cr2O7^{2-}}$.

Comment: Sorry I was not taught about any details of the reaction, only the reactions were taught. Very nice explanation! Thank you!

Comment: @MaxPayne No worries, that's what we are here for :)